# In Jmeter, for ISO8583 Sampler, how can I read the data from CSV file?

Tags: jmeter, iso8583

I have a Jmeter ISO8583 Sampler, where we have to paas the request data in the form of Data elements:
[image: Iso8583 Sampler request]

[image: CSV file]

Now, I want to put this data in a CSV file and read it from there.

The issue I am getting that it's picking only first data element from CSV.

I need to read all the rows from the CSV file and put it in Iso8583 sampler request and then execute.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - it will read next line on next iteration of each virtual user. In order to read all values during 1st iteration - convert them into 29 columns instead of 29 rows
2. In case you cannot control the CSV file format the options are in:

   - switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
   - or add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request and create the values using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

     ```
     sampler.addField('00', '0100')
     sampler.addField('02','52250000000015')
     //etc
     ```

Comment: Thanks for responding. If I'll add a JSR223 PreProcessor then again I have to add all the data elements manually...      sampler.addField('00', '0100')
sampler.addField('02','52250000000015')
//etc.      which is not solving my purpose. I want to create multiple CSV files for different scenarios and I should be able use 1 iso8583 sampler request by passing diff. CSV file

Comment: In other words you want us to do your job for you for free? Here you go as an exception: `new File('test.csv').readLines().each { line -> sampler.addField(line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1]) }` I would recommend getting familiarized with [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates) article but given the way you take screenshots I don't think it makes a lot of sense.